# VS code error : exited with code 1 in mac os

Tags: visual-studio-code

```
Running] cd "/Users/abhiaryan/Desktop/c+++/" && g++ demo.cpp -o demo && "/Users/abhiaryan/Desktop/c+++/"demo
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.052 seconds
```

the screen shots are here

[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code, errors etc. text. Copy the original text to your question and format it with the code format tool.

Answer (score 0):

go to settings > search for run > select save file before run
It resolved my same issue.